# Cart phtml file magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I am looking for the cart `.phtml` file. I can edit an image line in there or a static block for my storeviews like in below picture:

[image: 1]

I cannot locale the file to edit. Which location do I need to search?

My magento_checkout folder:

[image: cart folder]

My magento-checkout folder:

[image]

Comment: If it's a frontend design change, Your `Magento_Checkout` module isn't following the same folder structure as the Vendor, it should do. 
 If it's a module extension, `app/code/<Vendor>/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml` - also you need to make sure the layout.xml (`checkout_cart_index.xml`) references your namespace and the overriden node.

Comment: I do not have a app/code/<vendor>/Magento_checkout folder

Comment: The block needs to be above the `default.phtml` objects. It needs to be underneath the `page.title` element. URL: https://www.thefixedgearshop.com/nl/checkout/cart/

Answer (score 0):

To add any block / text above cart items ( as shown in image ) you can edit  :

```
Theme_Name/Magento_Checkout/templates/cart.phtml
```

however if you are in Developer mode and you want to find specific file where you want to make change you can go to admin and enable template path hints ( frontend ) it will show you all template locations block wise , from there you can find the template and make your changes :
add 
    Stores->Configurations->Advanced->Developer

under devloper tab you will find "**Enabled Template Path Hints for Storefront**" change that to "**Yes**".

NOTE :

This setting will work for website option not for "Default config settings" so you would need to change store/site to enable these settings.

Comment: I checked and I don't have any related files there. See edit on the original post. I also cannot change the path hints on cause I am in production mode.

Comment: what is your theme path ? if there are not these files then, you can copy files from magento-checkout folder to your theme Magento_Checkout folder

Comment: cart/item/default.phtml is the file you need to edit / add desired changes

Comment: The theme path is: app - design - frontend - smartwave - porto - Magento_Checkout but that folder is indeed a bit empty. The magento-checkout folder is filled like above edit of that folder.

Comment: default.phtml is not the correct file. This is based on the products in the cart.

Comment: you want to show image above cart item listing ? or under items image ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74628/discussion-between-naveed-and-axel-dekker).